# Set state of react component by using redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How I can assign some values of redux store to my component local state?

I should use redux actions to get data from API in my componentDidMount() method. Am I right? after getting data by redux   I want to set my component's state using the data from redux store.I got an error *this.props.article is undefined.*, but redux devtools shows that article object exists.

Where I supposed to call **this.setState()** method ??? I tried to call it in ***componentWillRecieveProps***() or ***componentDidUpdate***() , but unsuccessfuly.
 Please any help.Thank you in advance.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Typography,Spin } from 'antd';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getArticleDetails} from '../store/actions/articles';



class ArticleEdit extends Component {
    articleID = this.props.match.params.articleID; 
    state={

        str:'initial'
    }
    onChange = (str) => {
        console.log('Content change:', str);
        this.setState({ str1:str });

      };
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getArticleDetails(this.articleID);// GET data from api
        this.setState({str:this.props.article.title});// returns undefined

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.props.article===undefined?(<Spin/>):
                    (
                    <div>
                        <div style={{marginRight:'500px'}}>
                          <Paragraph editable={{ onChange: this.onChange}}>                          
                               {this.state.str}
                          </Paragraph>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )}    
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
    article: state.articleReducer.articles[0],    
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getArticleDetails})(ArticleEdit);
```

Comment: Technically, you should *not* set the data coming from your API as local state, if you've used action creators/thunks to fetch it, when using Redux. You should just use it as `props`.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. But I have an onChange method which I want to use for edit the Title of my article. So thats why I thought  I should use  state.  How I can handle onChange method without state???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Henrik said, you want to use `this.props` instead of `this.state`.  You already retrieve an article using mapStateToProps, which is good.  If you want to pass the article title to your  component, you can add some code in your render() method, like so:

```
render() {
    const { article } = this.props
    const { title } = article
    return (
            ...
                      <Paragraph editable={{ onChange: this.onChange}}>                          
                           {title}
                      </Paragraph>
            ...
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer,but then  how I can work with my onChange method ???

Comment: @PrunusArmeniaca if you're using Redux to manage your state, you'll need to set up an action and reducer to change the redux store.  Your title should not be changed in the React Component's state only.  Does that answer your question?